# Put text under drag-n-drop area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to help my users make choices by adding some tips in the form of text "underneath" the drop areas in my script. This causes the draggable button to lock in underneath the text and look plain ol' ugly.

In my example here the draggable button fits OK in "Box 3", but what can I do to make it fit the same way (and hide the tip) in "Box 2"?

And, imagine that the buttons have different values (numbers that is). How would I go about writing a script that adds these values and prints them out in "Summary"?

The values are not present in the text inside the button. To be honest - I don't really know where to put the values. I guess I could do a "massive" if-else and add a certain value if the innerHTML equals bla bla - but that seems very childlish...

And please, Vanilla only - I'm trying to learn this right.

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

// Legger til en eventlistener på alle knappene
for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcID", ev.target.id);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < dropTarget.length; i++) {
  dropTarget[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  });

  dropTarget[i].addEventListener("drop", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let target = ev.target;
    let srcID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcID");

    let droppable = target.classList.contains("wrapper");

    if (droppable) {
      target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcID));
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.bord-box {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.box2 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.button {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}

.mottak {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 1</p>
    <div class="bord-box wrapper">
      <button id="value1" class="button" draggable="true">Text 1</button>
      <button id="value2" class="button" draggable="true">Text 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 2</p>
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="mottak wrapper">
        Move button here ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 3</p>
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="mottak wrapper">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:50px;">
    <p>Summary</p>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>Sum value of buttons Text 1 and Text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks soulshined! That's much better and I'll present stuff like that from start in the future.

Comment: np, when you say 'underneath' you don't actually mean under (below) the element right? You are trying to say, a placeholder text, or maybe text that has a different `z-index`?

Comment: You are correct, soulshined. It's difficult to explain certain things in general - and it does not help when English is not your (my) native toungue... The "Move button here..." is kind of like a placeholder text. I've been experementing with Z-index on this one - but so far I've only gotten more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple quick fix just by adding a pseudo class to the `.mottak` elements. However, please note there can't be any whitespace in the elements for `:empty` to work.

`.mottak:empty::before` essentially only add's the `content` property to that element if it is empty (has no children)

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

// Legger til en eventlistener på alle knappene
for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcID", ev.target.id);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < dropTarget.length; i++) {
  dropTarget[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  });

  dropTarget[i].addEventListener("drop", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let target = ev.target;
    let srcID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcID");

    let droppable = target.classList.contains("wrapper");

    if (droppable) {
      target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcID));
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/** added */

.mottak:empty::before {
  content: "Move button here...";
}

/* end of edit */

.bord-box {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.box2 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.button {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}

.mottak {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 1</p>
    <div class="bord-box wrapper">
      <button id="value1" class="button" draggable="true">Text 1</button>
      <button id="value2" class="button" draggable="true">Text 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 2</p>
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="mottak wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 3</p>
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="mottak wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:50px;">
    <p>Summary</p>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>Sum value of buttons Text 1 and Text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's so sweet - and psuedo classes have not yet been in my "vocabulary" so this will most def push me forward!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. What I have done is deleting the text node contained inside the target `mottak wrapper` before inserting the dragged button.

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

// Legger til en eventlistener på alle knappene
for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcID", ev.target.id);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < dropTarget.length; i++) {
  dropTarget[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  });

  dropTarget[i].addEventListener("drop", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let target = ev.target;
    let srcID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcID");

    let droppable = target.classList.contains("wrapper");

    if (droppable) {

      // Here
      target.innerHTML = '';

      target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcID));
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.bord-box {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.box2 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.button {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}

.mottak {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 1</p>
    <div class="bord-box wrapper">
      <button id="value1" class="button" draggable="true">Text 1</button>
      <button id="value2" class="button" draggable="true">Text 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 2</p>
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="mottak wrapper">
        Move button here ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:50px;">
    <p>Box 3</p>
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="mottak wrapper">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:50px;">
    <p>Summary</p>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>Sum value of buttons Text 1 and Text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: just a heads up, this deletes the nodes in every box. For example, if you were to drag `Text 1` button back to Box 1 and `Text 2` button is still there it will delete `Text 2`.

Comment: Ah. But now - why did I not think of that? That's obviously the perfect, simple, answer. At least to my first question. Thank you - amedina!

Comment: @Jonas__G You're welcome. Anyway, the basic idea is there. I don't think it would be difficult to adapt it.

Comment: Hm. I guess soulshined is ahead of me. Could one use the same principle, but change z-index (testing as I write here)?

Comment: I think if you focus on z-index it's going to be just as 'ugly' imo, because you'll still see the text behind the button if the button's dimensions don't cover all the text. You could use `:before` or `:after` psuedo classes @Jonas__G

Comment: Or `display: none`.

Comment: Thanks good folks. Enough food here to solve this problem when my brain gets it's desired rest - I think. Any ideas on the second question (if your still awake)? Can I create some kind of an attribute to the button element  that holds a value and read it with js?

Comment: the answer is yes. @Jonas__G but stackoverflow generally frowns upon asking many different questions in 1 post. It's not SEO friendly for people looking for the same answer

Comment: Makes sense - soulshined. I'll dig into that and hope I can figure it out without creating another noob-thread while at it :-) Thanks again - and have a great evening!